# Wordpress Ultimate Member: show profile info on account page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

I made a custom registration form with a few extra fields using the ultimate member plugin. I want to display these extra fields on the account page. I already created an extra tab for it with hooks (see code below), but I can’t seem to find how to get the data from the extra fields of the register form. Does anyone has an idea?

Kind regards
Davy

```
/* Ultimate member */
/* tab Stormbee registration */

add_filter('um_account_page_default_tabs_hook', 'my_custom_tab_in_um', 100 );
function my_custom_tab_in_um( $tabs ) {
    $tabs[800]['mytab']['icon'] = 'um-faicon-pencil';
    $tabs[800]['mytab']['title'] = 'Stormbee registration';
    $tabs[800]['mytab']['custom'] = true;
    return $tabs;
}

/* make our new tab hookable */

add_action('um_account_tab__mytab', 'um_account_tab__mytab');
function um_account_tab__mytab( $info ) {
    global $ultimatemember;
    extract( $info );

    $output = $ultimatemember->account->get_tab_output('mytab');
    if ( $output ) { echo $output; }
}

/* Finally we add some content in the tab */

add_filter('um_account_content_hook_mytab', 'um_account_content_hook_mytab');
function um_account_content_hook_mytab( $output ){
    ob_start();
    ?>

    <div class="um-field">

        <?php echo um_user('display_name'); ?> <br />

        <?php

        ?>

    </div>      

    <?php

    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}

/* Ultimate member */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimate Member stores the data from the fields in the User Meta table. In order to display the saved field values in the front end, you can use Wordpress's built-in get_user_meta function:

```
echo get_user_meta( $user_ID, $key, true );
```

You could use `get_current_user_id()` to retrieve the current user's ID. But since you are planning on displaying this on the Ultimate Member Account Page (which admins can access), I recommend you use `UM()->user()->target_id` instead. This will pull the ID of the user whose profile/account page you are viewing.

Next, all you need to do is figure out the key of the field. Usually, this is all lowercase with underscores. So something like `first_name`.

Here's what the final code would look like:

```
$user_ID = UM()->user()->target_id;
echo get_user_meta( $user_ID, 'description', true );
```